# Windows Service Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, when starting a Windows Service I receive this error

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Security.SecurityException
Stack:
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(System.String, System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(System.String, System.String, Boolean)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(System.String)
   at GateePrinterMonitor.Service1..ctor()
   at GateePrinterMonitor.Service1.Main()
```

As account I am using `LocalService` any idea how I could solve this issue?

```
Public Class Service1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.
        EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStop.")
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        'InitializeComponent()
        MyBase.New()
        InitializeComponent()
        If Not System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource") Then
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource",
            "MyNewLog")
        End If
        EventLog1.Source = "MySource"
        EventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog"

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using LocalSystem instead? It looks to me like LocalService doesn't have permissions to access the event log - it's a relatively unprivileged user.